# C# - Winamp Style 3-Window snapped application

Tags: winforms, .net-2.0, c#-2.0

How can I create a Winamp-Style multiple-form snapped application in C# and .net 2.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy!

1. Create three forms
2. Add code to custom-draw *everything* on those three forms
3. Add logic to handle the user clicking and dragging anywhere on any of the forms, such that the window is moved normally until it comes within a certain distance of another one of your own forms (or the edge of the screen), in which case you would snap the window position to that edge.

I look forward to your follow-up questions...

Comment: How can I run three windows at the same time and control each of them individually?

Comment: You can run any number of windows simultaneously, provided you don't block the message pump. There's no real trick to it... you just create and show the windows.

Answer (score 3):

this works perfect for Windows Forms http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/stickywindows.aspx