# Two windows with glue

Tags: wpf

I want to show in my application two windows, which are glued, that means, if I move one window, the other will move the same vector too. The behaviour like in winamp, where we have playlist and track control as a separate "windows", but when glued they move as one.
Can't figure how to name it shortly, so I hope you'll understand me:)

Comment: @Matthew- have you looked here- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028024/snapping-sticky-wpf-windows

Comment: @RichardOD: Why didn't you post that as an answer?

Comment: @RichardOD, Why didn't you vote to close it as a dupe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy solution that I tried once was this -

- Instead of creating Windows create UserControls.
- Put the usercontrols in a StackPanel with Orientation=Horizontal
- Moving the window which contains these 2 usercontrols in a stackpanel will move both the usercontrols at the same time giving a Glue effect
- If for any condition you do not want to glue them, put the usercontrols in seperate windows.