# WPF - Anchoring window position to other than TopLeft

Tags: wpf, window, position, anchor

I'm trying to anchor a WPF Window (NOT a control inside a window) to TopRight for example, by default Windows anchors all windows to top left.

I tried the following code

```
    private void OnWindowSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        double delta = e.PreviousSize.Width - e.NewSize.Width;
        Left += delta;
    }
```

It works, but the window stutters/flickers during rapid size changes (e.g Animations)

I tried googling it but did not find a good solution, am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028024/snapping-sticky-wpf-windows) post.

Here's the code

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private double right;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
        HwndSource source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this) as HwndSource;
        right = Left + Width;
        source.AddHook(WndProc);
    }

    private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        if (msg == (int)WindowMessage.WindowPositionChanging)
        {
            var windowPosition = (WindowPosition)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(WindowPosition));
            bool isMove = !windowPosition.Flags.HasFlag(WindowPositionFlags.NoMove); //0x0002
            bool isSize = !windowPosition.Flags.HasFlag(WindowPositionFlags.NoSize); //0x0001

            if (isMove)
            {
                right = windowPosition.Left + windowPosition.Width;
            }
            else if (isSize)
            {
                windowPosition.Left = (int)(right - windowPosition.Width);
                windowPosition.Top = (int)Top;
                windowPosition.Flags = (WindowPositionFlags)((int)windowPosition.Flags & 0xfffd); //remove the NoMove flag
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(windowPosition, lParam, true);
            }

        }
        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }
```

Hope it helps someone