# WPF connect two windows to drag and resize

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to create a sort of side-window next to another window.
It should resize with the mainwindow and also move with it when I drag the mainwindow. How do I do this?

Comment: See this topic: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028024/snapping-sticky-wpf-windows

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the first thing you do is to create your second window.

```
SecondWindow secondwindow;
```

Then you call the window directly next to your MainWindow.

```
secondwindow = new Secondwindow();
secondwindow.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;
secondwindow.Left = this.Left + this.Width;
secondwindow.Top = this.Top;
secondwindow.Height = this.Height;
secondwindow.Show();
```

If you want the second window to resize with your `MainWindow` (I guess just the height) type this in your
MainWindow - SizeChanged - event.

```
private void mainwindow_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (secondwindow != null)
    {
        secondwindow.Left = this.Left + this.Width;
        secondwindow.Top = this.Top;
        secondwindow.Height = this.Height;
    }
}
```

Same without the height-change for the `LocationChanged`.

```
private void mainwindow_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (secondwindow != null)
    {
        secondwindow.Left = this.Left + this.Width;
        secondwindow.Top = this.Top;
    }
}
```